# defining class with generics inheritance and an interface

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to create a class that derives from ObservableCollection and restricts itself to only being used with a particular base class (BaseMetadata). It also needs to implement the IXmlSerializable interface as I am adding a persistence capability to the collection.

Here is the class definition of the collection...

```
public class CollectionMetadata<T> : ObservableCollection<T> where T : BaseMetadata,
                                     IXmlSerializable
{
    XmlSchema IXmlSerializable.GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
    }
}
```

...the BaseMetadata can be simplied to an empty class and still produce the error...

```
public class BaseMetadata
{
}
```

...I get the following error....

```
CollectionMetadata<T>.IXmlSerializable.GetSchema()': 
    containing type does not implementinterface 
    'System.Xml.Serialization.IXmlSerializable'
```

...on the following line from the above code...

```
XmlSchema IXmlSerializable.GetSchema()
```

I must be missing something really obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In it's current form, you're applying the `IXmlSerializable` as a constraint on the `T`; not declaring it as an interface of `CollectionMetadata<T>`.  So your explicit interface implementation is moaning, because it can't find the interface.

You just need to move the `IXmlSerializable` interface to *before* the constraint:

```
public class CollectionMetadata<T> : ObservableCollection<T>, IXmlSerializable
                                     where T : BaseMetadata
```

As a side note - it's potentially a really good thing that you used an explicit interface implementation for this, otherwise this could have been a real head-scratcher later on.  Because as a public method, the compiler wouldn't moan at this point, but would have complained if you'd tried to pass the collection as `IXmlSerializable`.

Answer (score 1):

You are saying that `T` implements the `IXmlSerializable` interface. Presumably, you *actually* mean to say that `ColelctionMetadata<T>` implements it:

```
public class CollectionMetadata<T> : ObservableCollection<T>, IXmlSerializable
      where T : BaseMetadata
```

For `ReadXml` and `WriteXml` it doesn't present as an issue, as even without the interface they just look like regular methods. However, the compiler won't let you use "explicit interface implementation" unless you really do implement those methods, and `XmlSchema IXmlSerializable.GetSchema()` is an explicit interface implementation.